# Are dictionary values automatically an optional?

Tags: swift, dictionary

Hey guys im new to swift and trying to work out some subtleties. That said, before I continue to code I want to solidify my understanding here. After running this code:

```
var content:[String:Double] = [:]
content["swords"] = 12
content["bows"] = 113
content["swords"]  = content["swords"] + 12 // problem line
```

I get the following:

`error: value of optional type 'Double?' not unwrapped;`

Does this mean that every value in a dictionary is an optional? I figured if that was true, then I can add just a key without a value and print it.

```
var content:[String:Double] = [:]
content["swords"] = 12
content["bows"] = 113
content["blade"]
print(content["blade"])
```

and it did in fact print `nil` so is this true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two completely different issues. In your second code you never assign a value to the key `"blade"` which is why the `print` statement shows `nil`.

The line:

```
content["blade"]
```

does not add anything. It actually attempts to access the value at that key.

The problem with the first bit of code is simply because the value of any dictionary lookup is an optional value because at runtime there is no guarantee there is a value for a given key.

You can fix the code by doing:

```
content["swords"]  = content["swords"]! + 12
```

But don't do that. Instead, do it safely:

```
if let swords = content["swords"] as? Double {
    content["swords"] = swords + 12
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries usually return nil if a key is not set. You did not add a key without a value, you just read a not set key twice, thus returning nil both times (one time doing nothing, the second time printing it).

Comment: but values when they do exist are optionals, right?

Comment: As this is Swifts way of letting you know that you should check for undefined keys - yes, they are.